# mysql2, rvm, ruby 1.9.2

Tags: mysql, ruby, osx-snow-leopard, rvm

I am starting a new RoR project and thought I would use ruby 1.9.2 (up until now I've always used REE 1.8.7).
I am on a mac with Snow Leopard and using rvm.

I did

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

in my Gemfile I have:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~>0.2.6'
```

But I am getting this when trying to run db:migrate:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
Bundling your gems. This may take a few minutes on first run.
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lxxxx/gems/mysql2-0.2.8/lib/mysql2/client.rb:19: [BUG] unknown type 0x22 (0xc given)
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0049 p:---- s:0176 b:0176 l:000175 d:000175 CFUNC  :init_connection
c:0048 p:0028 s:0173 b:0173 l:000172 d:000172 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/mysql2-0.2.8/lib/mysql2/client.rb:19
c:0047 p:---- s:0162 b:0162 l:000161 d:000161 FINISH
c:0046 p:---- s:0160 b:0160 l:000159 d:000159 CFUNC  :new
c:0045 p:0101 s:0156 b:0156 l:000155 d:000155 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/mysql2-0.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:1
c:0044 p:0045 s:0150 b:0150 l:000149 d:000149 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
c:0043 p:0011 s:0147 b:0147 l:000146 d:000146 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
c:0042 p:0048 s:0143 b:0143 l:000129 d:000142 BLOCK  /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
c:0041 p:---- s:0140 b:0140 l:000139 d:000139 FINISH
c:0040 p:---- s:0138 b:0138 l:000137 d:000137 CFUNC  :loop
c:0039 p:0009 s:0135 b:0135 l:000129 d:000134 BLOCK  /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
c:0038 p:0019 s:0133 b:0133 l:000132 d:000132 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201
c:0037 p:0013 s:0130 b:0130 l:000129 d:000129 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
c:0036 p:0030 s:0127 b:0124 l:000123 d:000123 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
c:0035 p:0033 s:0121 b:0121 l:000120 d:000120 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
c:0034 p:0018 s:0116 b:0116 l:000115 d:000115 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
c:0033 p:0011 s:0113 b:0113 l:000112 d:000112 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
c:0032 p:0020 s:0110 b:0110 l:000109 d:000109 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:488
c:0031 p:---- s:0104 b:0104 l:000103 d:000103 FINISH
c:0030 p:---- s:0102 b:0102 l:000101 d:000101 CFUNC  :new
c:0029 p:0020 s:0096 b:0096 l:000095 d:000095 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:435
c:0028 p:0083 s:0091 b:0091 l:000090 d:000090 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:417
c:0027 p:0102 s:0086 b:0086 l:001338 d:000085 BLOCK  /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142
c:0026 p:---- s:0084 b:0084 l:000083 d:000083 FINISH
c:0025 p:---- s:0082 b:0082 l:000081 d:000081 CFUNC  :call
c:0024 p:0043 s:0077 b:0077 l:000068 d:000076 BLOCK  /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205
c:0023 p:---- s:0074 b:0074 l:000073 d:000073 FINISH
c:0022 p:---- s:0072 b:0072 l:000071 d:000071 CFUNC  :each
c:0021 p:0173 s:0069 b:0069 l:000068 d:000068 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200
c:0020 p:0111 s:0065 b:0065 l:000059 d:000064 BLOCK  /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158
c:0019 p:0019 s:0063 b:0063 l:000062 d:000062 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201
c:0018 p:0033 s:0060 b:0060 l:000059 d:000059 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151
c:0017 p:0048 s:0053 b:0053 l:000052 d:000052 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144
c:0016 p:0045 s:0048 b:0048 l:000047 d:000047 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112
c:0015 p:0012 s:0041 b:0041 l:000026 d:000040 BLOCK  /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90
c:0014 p:---- s:0038 b:0038 l:000037 d:000037 FINISH
c:0013 p:---- s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 CFUNC  :each
c:0012 p:0069 s:0033 b:0033 l:000026 d:000032 BLOCK  /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90
c:0011 p:0009 s:0031 b:0031 l:000030 d:000030 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129
c:0010 p:0011 s:0027 b:0027 l:000026 d:000026 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84
c:0009 p:0029 s:0024 b:0024 l:000017 d:000023 BLOCK  /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62
c:0008 p:0009 s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129
c:0007 p:0011 s:0018 b:0018 l:000017 d:000017 METHOD /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59
c:0006 p:0048 s:0015 b:0015 l:000014 d:000014 TOP    /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
c:0005 p:---- s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0011 b:0011 l:000010 d:000010 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0127 s:0007 b:0007 l:0014e8 d:0009f0 EVAL   /Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/bin/rake:19
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0014e8 d:0014e8 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:417:in `migrate'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:435:in `up'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:435:in `new'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:488:in `initialize'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:317:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:94:in `connection'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in `checkout'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:187:in `block in checkout'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:187:in `loop'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:191:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:237:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `new_connection'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/mysql2-0.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `mysql2_connection'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/mysql2-0.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `new'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/mysql2-0.2.8/lib/mysql2/client.rb:19:in `initialize'
/Users/smyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lotteryportal/gems/mysql2-0.2.8/lib/mysql2/client.rb:19:in `init_connection'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001001806f2 rb_vm_bugreport + 210
1   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010003a094 report_bug + 372
2   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010003a258 rb_bug + 200
3   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010003bd26 rb_check_type + 166
4   mysql2.bundle                       0x0000000100701bbd init_connection + 29
5   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017bc03 vm_call_method + 931
6   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100167db4 vm_exec_core + 8260
7   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010016fa53 vm_exec + 1507
8   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001001714ba vm_call0 + 1290
9   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017642e rb_funcall2 + 350
10  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100090263 rb_class_new_instance + 51
11  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017bc03 vm_call_method + 931
12  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100167db4 vm_exec_core + 8260
13  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010016fa53 vm_exec + 1507
14  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017df91 loop_i + 561
15  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010003f227 rb_rescue2 + 519
16  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100162ca6 rb_f_loop + 54
17  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017bc03 vm_call_method + 931
18  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100167db4 vm_exec_core + 8260
19  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010016fa53 vm_exec + 1507
20  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001001714ba vm_call0 + 1290
21  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017642e rb_funcall2 + 350
22  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100090263 rb_class_new_instance + 51
23  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017bc03 vm_call_method + 931
24  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100167db4 vm_exec_core + 8260
25  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010016fa53 vm_exec + 1507
26  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100170dcd rb_vm_invoke_proc + 877
27  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100046a8e proc_call + 94
28  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017bc03 vm_call_method + 931
29  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100167db4 vm_exec_core + 8260
30  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010016fa53 vm_exec + 1507
31  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017cf00 rb_yield + 640
32  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100009612 rb_ary_each + 82
33  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017bc03 vm_call_method + 931
34  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100167db4 vm_exec_core + 8260
35  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010016fa53 vm_exec + 1507
36  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017cf00 rb_yield + 640
37  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100009612 rb_ary_each + 82
38  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017bc03 vm_call_method + 931
39  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100167db4 vm_exec_core + 8260
40  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010016fa53 vm_exec + 1507
41  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010016fef0 rb_iseq_eval + 368
42  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010004223c rb_load_internal + 300
43  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001000439ed rb_f_load + 109
44  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010017bc03 vm_call_method + 931
45  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100167db4 vm_exec_core + 8260
46  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010016fa53 vm_exec + 1507
47  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010016fd5b rb_iseq_eval_main + 507
48  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010003f492 ruby_exec_internal + 178
49  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000100041e1c ruby_run_node + 60
50  ruby                                0x0000000100000ecf main + 79
51  ruby                                0x0000000100000e74 start + 52
52  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: And what happens when you run `bundle install`?

Comment: tried `gem mysql2 --version "~>0.2.6"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check following

```
# install the mysql server locally
brew install mysql
# install the gem
gem install mysql2
```